# Отправить POST из js в php

Tags: javascript, php

Не понимаю в чём проблема.
Задача такая: Нужно отправить из js данные в php и вывести их.

Код js:

```
function send_data(){
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var info = "123321";
   request.open("POST", "http://localhost/index.php");
   request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   request.send('info=' + info);  
}
```

Код php:

```
$info = $_POST['info'];
echo $info;
```

Лог Apache:

```
localhost: 127.0.0.1 [22/Jan/2020:17:04:15 +0300] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 
200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
```

Просто ничего не происходит, вроде и отправляется всё нормально, но php ничего не выводит.

Comment: А куда php должен вывести данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение

Чтобы вывести данные вы должны работать с ответом сервера. А если точнее то с `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` проверяя `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`; В коде ниже я добавил простой пример вывода возвращенных данных через alert();

```
function send_data() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var info = "123321";
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open("POST", "http://localhost/index.php");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('info=' + info);
}
```

Подробнее про response:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response

Подробнее про XMLHttpRequest с примерами:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Ещё вариант - это использовать ajax через библиотеку jQuery. Она в отличие от XMLHttpRequest совместима с древними браузерами IE и лучше адаптирована под мелкие баги и особенности конкретных браузеров.

Подробнее: https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1452&rub=32

### Что вы должны понять

php код выполняется в момент обращения к нему. Вы по JS отправляете данные и на этом заканчиваете работу. Соответственно php принимает данные, обрабатывает и тоже завершает работу.

Если вы пытаетесь посмотреть результат через браузер, то когда вы открываете страницу - это новое обращение и новое выполнение скрипта, никак не связанное с вашим запросом через JS. Поэтому если вам требуется вывести данные после отправки - нужно их тут же получить.